# interact with the private stellar network

Tags: javascript-sdk, go-sdk

I have started my own private stellar network using the below command.

```
docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --standalone
```

How do I interact with it? How can I create account in it and do transactions?